# How to terraform for step execution in EMR?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-emr, bootstrapping

I am trying to execute a bash script as a step in EMR once bootstrapping completes. However it keeps on failing with following error in stderr file:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bash,-c,'cd /mnt; chmod +x
>   ./userdata.sh; ./userdata.sh'" (in directory "."): error=2, No such
>   file or directory

Step code in terraform is following:

```
step {
action_on_failure = "CONTINUE"
name = "Setup Hadoop configuration"
hadoop_jar_step {
jar = "command-runner.jar"
args = ["bash,-c,'cd /mnt; chmod +x ./userdata.sh; ./userdata.sh'"]
}
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? Any error in syntax or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `args = ["bash", "-c","'cd /mnt; chmod +x ./userdata.sh; ./userdata.sh'"]`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply beny. I tried what you mentioned and this time it failed with following error message: Command exiting with ret '127'